# Error: [postcss-custom-media] "importFrom" is no longer supported

Tags: css, postcss

I have a project that use `postcss-custom-media` library and recently I upgrade all libraries since they were very old. While doing upgrade ablove library got upgrade to 10.0.1 from 7.0.8. Now the build throws following error for couple of places.

```
./components/add-response/add-response.module.css
Error: [postcss-custom-media] "importFrom" is no longer supported
    at creator (/home/ravinda/Codes/npp_srilanka/community-forum-frontend/node_modules/postcss-custom-media/dist/index.cjs:1:7381)
    at /home/ravinda/Codes/npp_srilanka/community-forum-frontend/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/config/blocks/css/plugins.js:67:63
    at plugin (/home/ravinda/Codes/npp_srilanka/community-forum-frontend/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/config/blocks/css/plugins.js:35:44)
    at Processor.normalize (/home/ravinda/Codes/npp_srilanka/community-forum-frontend/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:36:13)
    at new Processor (/home/ravinda/Codes/npp_srilanka/community-forum-frontend/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:11:25)
    at postcss (/home/ravinda/Codes/npp_srilanka/community-forum-frontend/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js:26:10)
    at /home/ravinda/Codes/npp_srilanka/community-forum-frontend/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/config/blocks/css/index.js:127:37
    at async /home/ravinda/Codes/npp_srilanka/community-forum-frontend/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js:51:40
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/ravinda/Codes/npp_srilanka/community-forum-frontend/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:105:20)
```

Following is the `postcss.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-nested': {},
    'postcss-custom-media': {
      importFrom: [
        {
          customMedia: { '--m': '(min-width: 640px)' }
        },
        ,
        {
          customMedia: { '--t': '(min-width: 980px)' }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My UI/UX understanding is very poor but it seems like a alias becase `--t` and `--,` has been used in other files.

```
  @media (--t) {
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 0;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 250px;
  }
```

I couldn't find now to resolve this error but saw that `postcss-custom-media` is deprecated and should use `postcss-preset-env` rather. But I couldn't fiture out how to same with that.

Any tips on how to get the resolved with minimum changes is much appriciate.

Answer (score 1):

`postcss-custom-media` is not deprecated.

Only the `importFrom` plugin option was removed.

See https://github.com/csstools/postcss-plugins/discussions/192 for more information.

Summary :

The `importFrom` mechanic was a bad fit for some PostCSS plugins.
Those plugins focussed on being polyfills for standard features first.

`importFrom` is purely a hack to solve other issues and isn't part of the polyfill.

This mechanic has been fully removed and you have to migrate to another solution.

Something like `@csstools/postcss-global-data` works for most people.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@csstools/postcss-global-data

Answer (score 0):

Following got rid of the build errors. Yets to see if stying works same becase app is not working properly due to other depcrecated things.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-nested': {},
    'postcss-custom-media': {
      customMedia: {
        '--m' : '(min-width: 640px)',
        '--t': '(min-width: 980px)',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work. `customMedia` is not a known plugin option so the functionality from `importFrom` won't be restored by randomly using a different name :)

Comment: @RMenke Yes, It just got rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

use postcss-preset-env

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-nested': {},
    'postcss-preset-env': {
      stage: 1, // Enables custom properties and media queries
      features: {
        'custom-media-queries': {
          preserve: false,
          importFrom: [
            {
              customMedia: {
                '--m': '(min-width: 640px)',
                '--t': '(min-width: 980px)'
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Still get the error. 

Error: [postcss-custom-media] "importFrom" is no longer supported
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)

I uninstalled postcss-custom-media and installed postcss-preset-env but seems like it is using internally.

Comment: Correct, this change won't help because one plugin is just a container for many plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Used `post-custom-media-generator` to get the same funtionality.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-nested': {},
    'postcss-custom-media-generator': {
      // you can pass in any arbitrary key, and any valid CSS media query value
      '--m' : '(min-width: 640px)',
      '--t': '(min-width: 980px)',
    },
    'postcss-preset-env': {},
  }
};
```

Comment: This has no effect for me. Is the `'postcss-preset-env': {},` required for the `postcss-custom-media-generator` to work?